# Xamarin Studio: no proper text is displayed

Tags: xamarin-studio

I downloaded the `XamarinStudio.app` but this is the only thing I see when I start the application:
[image]

Did anyone every encounter this issue before?

Also launching the app directly from the DMG gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that simply waiting for an update fixed the issue. I got an update popup, downloaded and installed it and now everything looks good.